# How can i get data from Mongodb using mongoose, nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm just started learning Nodejs, mongodb, reactjs and having a trouble.

I'm trying to get data from mongodb.

backend code:

```
app.post('/tweet',(req,res)=>{
    tweetData.find((err,data)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.json({success: false, error: err});
        }
        return res.json({success: true, data:data});
    });
})
```

font end code:

```
class TweetContainer extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data:null,
            API_URL : 'http://localhost:5000/tweet'
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){

        fetch(this.state.API_URL)
        .then(response=>response.json)
        .then(result=>{
            this.setState({
                data: result.data
            });
            console.log(this.state.data)
        });

    }
    render(){

        return(
            <div id="main">
                <h2>Tweet</h2>
                <div id="stream">

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

when i log the data, console show undefined.

What i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit 1:

You're also querying with mongoose, wrong as it takes the first argument as the query:

```
app.post('/tweet',(req,res)=>{
    tweetData.find(queryObject || {}, (err,data)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.json({success: false, error: err});
        }
        return res.json({success: true, data:data});
    });
})
```

You're logging the state immediately after you're updating it, let me tell you that's not how it works, it doesn't immediately update the state, so you have to wait for it to do.

You can pass a callback to `setState`, so that it executes the callback after the state change has been completed, something like this:

```
this.setState({ data: result.data }, () => {
    console.log(this.state)
})
```

Comment: the log is null, this case, what should i do? i want use the data in the render function.

Comment: yes, i got it. but now i have a trouble with the response. i can access to whole of the data. but when i using dot operator to access the data. it is null. why

Comment: what dot operator? please explain @vuogvuog

Comment: sorry my bad in English. this meant that i can show data to console using console.log(data). but when i access properties by the property name, (example: data.success)               the log show: null. https://i.imgur.com/T37VknJ.png